# lwjgl: Size of the display mode does not change when i re size the window.

Tags: java, lwjgl

I create a window with this code:

```
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.setResizable(true);
        Display.create();
```

Every game loop i attempt to get the size of the window:

```
        width = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        height = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
        tick();
        render();
        otherStuff();
        Display.update();
```

Now my problem accures because `Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();` always returns the original size  the window, and does not change if i re-size the window.

I need to get the new size of the window after the user re-sizes it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Display.getWidth()`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#getWidth%28%29) and [`Display.getHeight()`](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#getHeight%28%29) should do what you want.

Comment: Hmm... everywhere i searched, it always said `Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth();`. I think that this is kind of a derp on lwjgl's part.